# How to print a triangle using 3 repetitive alphabets

Tags: python

So basically i got this objective:
I want the user to choose the number of lines of the triangle. Then i want to print the triangle using only the 3 first letters of the alphabet:`a,b,c`

```
Input = 5
```

output :

```
a
ab
abc
abca
abcab
```

I have tried this code :

```
n = int(input("Give me the number of lines:"))
alphabets = "abc"
for i in range(0, n + 1):
    print(alphabets[0:i])
```

But it doesn't work, any guidance?

Comment: what is `ch` supposed to mean?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to print more elements than the list has. You can try this instead:

```
for i in range(n+1):
    for j in range(i):
        print(alphabets[j%3], end ="")
    print("")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like (find the explanation in comment)

```py
n=int(input("Give me the number of lines :"))
alphabets="abc"
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for i in range(i):
        print(alphabets[i%len(alphabets)], end='') 
        # end='' so that it does not create new line
        # i%len(alphabets) will do circulat indexing. Like for i=4
        # 4%3 will be 1 so it will give b
        # check modulo operator for more
    print() # this pring will just add a newline
```

```
Give me the number of lines :5
a
ab
abc
abca
abcab
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).

```
import itertools

alphabet = "abc"

n = int(input('Number of lines: '))
for i in range(1, n+1):
    print(''.join(itertools.islice(itertools.cycle(alphabet), i)))
```

[`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) will repeat `alphabet` as long as needed and [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) takes the appropriate amount of characters from the generator created by `cycle`.

If you want to store those lines in a list to use them later, then replace the loop with this list comprehension:

```
result = [''.join(itertools.islice(itertools.cycle(alphabet), i)) for i in range(1, n+1)]
```

If `n` is `6` you'll get `['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abca', 'abcab', 'abcabc']` as the content of `result`.

Comment: why bro? why canon to kill a mosquito? He ,might have just started learning python!

Comment: There were other answers already and I wanted to show a different approach. Too many Python developers don't know about the power of `itertools` and this shows part of the possibilities.